# Python: How to write a script to compile and run a C++ program via CMake?

Tags: python, c++, cmake

Assuming I have the following project structure,

```
|   CMakeLists.txt
|   run_experiments.py
+---libs
\---src
        main.cpp
        main.h
```

how to make `run_experiments.py` compile the program via CMake and run it multiple times with different command-line arguments? What I've tried:

```
# run_experiments.py

import os

os.system("mkdir bin build")
os.chdir("build")
os.system('cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ..')
os.system("make")
# and so on...
```

But it already looks ugly, and I'm looking for the most elegant and cross-platform solution (Windows with MinGW and Linux, for example).

**UPD:** Added my `CMakeLists.txt`, which is CLion default-generated:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test_tokenizing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(test_tokenizing src/main.cpp src/main.h)
```

Comment: [`cmake --build`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html#build-and-test) can help you avoid some of the platform-specific binaries such as `make`.  And you can use things like [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) to avoid calling some OS-specific commands.  You will probably still need a subprocess to call `cmake`, and for that I'd recommend the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system`.

Comment: Across *which* platforms?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Windows and Linux.

Comment: Unless `CMakeLists.txt` in your project contains a target for **run** the executable, you need to use name of that executable for run it. And this name is definitely **platform-dependent** (has `.exe` extension on Windows and has no extension on Linux).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know. So this must be taken into account in the Python code, which will determine on which platform it runs.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether it would be easier to build the C++ project with CMake and have CMake run the Python script once it has built the executable instead of using the python script to invoke CMake. With the presets feature introduced in CMake 3.19 users don't even need to specify all required CMake options anymore, which I suspect is the main reason you'd like to script the CMake invocation in the first place.

Comment: @Corristo Exactly a Python script must be an interface for doing it in my project. Also, I can't use this new version of CMake.

Comment: From your response to the answer by @jignatius I gather your issue is that you and your colleagues don't have a consistent build environment, which is why you can't assume CMake, NMake or Visual Studio to be in the PATH. So maybe this is an angle you could tackle instead, e.g. by providing a build environment in a docker container, or by using a package manager like Conan to not only package the library dependencies but also the build tools.

Regarding CMake 3.19: You can build it from source and install it to the git repo if that is the only remaining reason to have python invoke CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `subprocess` module will enable you to run external programs like CMake and the binary that you build with it. The executable name, however, will be different on Windows and Linux (with Windows having a .exe extension). You should be able to specify `./test_tokenizing` to run your program and the system should find it providing you specify the current working directory `cwd`.

Try this:

```
import os
import platform
import subprocess
import sys


def main(*args):
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    build_dir = os.path.join(current_directory, 'build')

    if not os.path.exists(build_dir):
        os.makedirs(build_dir)

    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        exe = os.path.join(build_dir, 'test_tokenizing.exe')
    else:
        exe = os.path.join(build_dir, 'test_tokenizing')

    cmake_args = ['-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=' + build_dir]
    cmake_args += ['-G', 'Unix Makefiles']

    subprocess.run(['cmake', ".."] + cmake_args, cwd=build_dir, check=True)
    subprocess.run(['cmake', '--build', '.'], cwd=build_dir, check=True)
    p = subprocess.run([exe, *args], cwd=build_dir, capture_output=True, text=True)
    print(p.stdout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = []
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        args += sys.argv[1:]
    main(*args)
```

(Requires Python 3.7+ for `capture_output` and `text` in `subprocess.run`).

Here you can pass command line arguments to the script like this:

```
python run_experiments.py hello world
```

and the arguments are forwarded to the function `main()`, which will in turn call your C++ executable with them.

**Edit:**

Just in case `./test_tokenizing` doesn't work on some exotic OS or you want to include some platform specific compiler/build flags, I've put a check for the platform above and specified the full path to your C++ executable.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it on Windows with MinGW and WSL Ubuntu, and it works just fine. But why use ```-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=``` instead of ```-B```, for example? Does it have to do anything with the C/C++ library? My project is an executable. What's the difference between using absolute paths, as you did, and the relative ones? Couldn't we remove the system's check by just prefixing the executable with ```./```? It's unnecessary to add ```.exe``` on Windows, as the other poster has said.

Comment: @kenticent You're right about using the prefix `./test_tokenizing`. See my update above. Regarding, `DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=`, I put it there in case you were building some libraries. This will put them in the build folder for you.

Comment: Thanks. I would like you to add the alternative version using ```if``` because it's useful in case you're working with some exotic OS or writing platform-dependent code in general.

Answer (score 1):

If the C++ code is not dynamically generated or something, I would recommend you build it upfront, before starting your python program and merely execute it from the python program.

If you have a good reason to build it from the python code, I created you a little example at https://github.com/kyotov/experiments. Something like this works for run_experiements.py:

```
import os
import subprocess


def main():
    os.makedirs('build', exist_ok=True)
    subprocess.check_call('cmake -B build -G "NMake Makefiles"', shell=True)
    subprocess.check_call('cmake --build .', shell=True, cwd='build')

    subprocess.check_call('experiments 1 2 3', shell=True, cwd='build')
    subprocess.check_call('experiments 2 3 4', shell=True, cwd='build')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I used the following for `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I run `python run_experiements.py` I get this output:

```
(base) C:\kamen\clion\experiments>python run_experiments.py
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/kamen/clion/experiments/build
[100%] Built target experiments
experiments
1
2
3
experiments
2
3
4
```

To get this to work, you will need to setup your environment correctly to find the tools you need. In my case I used Miniconda3 for python and then `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"` to get my compiler and cmake in the path.

I did not have a Linux machine handy, but if you make the `-G` conditional and use `Unix Makefiles` it will likely work on Linux (and elsewhere) too. Note that you don't have to bother with the `.exe` on Windows, because the shell is smart enough to start the program even if you don't specify it.

Comment: "To get this to work, you will need to setup your environment correctly to find the tools you need" - that's the problem. The script must be ready to use "out of the box," except for the moment when the user must add CMake and Make to PATH as I did in my case with MinGW. This code worked for it, but it won't work for Linux, where the executables must be prefixed with ```./```.

Comment: you can avoid the need for ./ on unix by running build/experiments without changing to the build folder... that causes a small problem on Windows because you need to use the opposite slash there. But you can construct the right path using `os.path.sep` for the path separator... There will be things like this, and unfortunately they will make the solution longer and longer.

Comment: what build systems do you want to support on windows? i fear that there is always some amount of pre-setup in order to put them in the path... MSVC? MinGW? Cygwin?